# How do I get an aabb's collision normal

Tags: physics, collision-resolution, aabb

I have two aabbs and I need to know the collision normal of the to help me slide the aabbs across themselves. I have searched google but nothing really came up.

How do I get the collision normal of two aabbs colliding together

Comment: Just so you know, the MTV isn't always the best thing to use when dealing with collisions. It might give you directions that completely differ from how it would've reacted, especiall, at corners.

Comment: Translation just means adding / subtracting from a position. Have you tried adding the MTV to your position? Did that give different results than what you wanted? If so, tell us about those results and how they differ from what you want.